# Why can some disjoint and exhaustive patterns not be represented as definitional equalities?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, agda, dependent-type, type-theory

I am currently reading through [Ulf Norell's PhD Thesis](https://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Eulfn/papers/thesis.pdf), where he describes the implementation of Agda.

In Chapter 2.2 (page 41), which is concerned with pattern matching with dependent types, he points out that some patterns - even when they are disjoint and exhaustive - cannot be represented as definitional equalities in the underlying core type theory. He illustrates that with the following example:

```
maj : Bool → Bool → Bool → Bool
maj true  true  true  = true
maj true  false z     = z
maj false y     true  = y
maj x     true  false = x
maj false false false = false
```

Unfortunately he does not prove or motivate this claim. Intuitively I think, it is true, because we probably cannot really 'count' using the core theory, but I have not found any proper argument that convinced me of the truth of this statement.

Could someone here please explain, why certain disjoint and exhaustive patterns not be represented as definitional equalities - maybe using the example above?

Comment: You have to split on one of the three arguments first, at which point one of the three middle clauses will not hold definitionally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Sorry for being a bit slow in understanding what exactly is happening. So you say that we have to split on `x`, `y` or `z`, when trying to show that we have definitional equalities, right? So, say we split `maj true false z = z` on `z`. Then we get `maj true false true = true` and `maj true false false = false`. Wouldn't one be able to show that both are definitional equalities in the underlying type system? And if not, why not?

Comment: No, I meant that you have to split when defining the case tree for the function. See Jesper's answer.

Comment: The two definitional equalities you got do not suffice to imply `maj true false z = z`, because `z` might not compute to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive discussion of this example in our paper "Overlapping and order-independent patterns" at ESOP 2014 (https://jesper.cx/files/overlapping-and-order-independent-patterns.pdf).

Basically, most proof assistants translate definitions by pattern matching to case trees (and sometimes further to eliminators), but there is no way to faithfully represent the `maj` function as a case tree. The reason for this is that a case tree forces you to make a decision on which argument to match first, but as soon as you match on any argument, the equation where that argument is a variable no longer holds as a definitional equality.